# MutationObserver called twice when space is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an observer to a content editable div.
When I press space, it is called twice.

```
// Write TypeScript code!
var appDiv: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div');

document.getElementById('app').appendChild(appDiv)
appDiv.setAttribute('contenteditable','true');
appDiv.innerText = 'Hello there';
var config = {    
  subtree: true,
    characterData: true,};
// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
      console.log(mutation)
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(appDiv, config);
```

Can anyone give an explanation? Is this expected behavior?
live demo: [stackblitz](https://typescript-zngvv9.stackblitz.io/)
If you open the `console` and hit one space, you can see that there are two `MutationRecord`
I test this on Chrome, however on firefox, instead of two records, I got three.
PS: for any other key struck, you got one mutation record, however if you press another letter after pressing space, in this case you also get two mutation record.

Comment: Can we see the stackblitz code also ?

Comment: It is the same as I posted here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zngvv9

Comment: Look at the mutationslist it will show you what mutations are happening. adding the space is going to affect the subtree and the characterdata so a mutation for each is going to be in the list

Comment: @PatrickEvans any suggestions? also on firefox I got tree records. If I set subtree to false, it will not detect any changes.

Comment: Well if you dont care about the actual mutations and only that something changed dont loop over the mutations, just do your action. Or loop over them but only do your action for a specific mutation, eg `if(mutation.type=='characterData')`. As for the different number of records that can probably be chalked up to the browsers having different opinions on what actions mutate what

Comment: For example, if you type 'x', you got one record. If you press space (2 records) and then press 'x' you also get 2 records. Maybe first listen to some kind of keyboard event ( first fire ) and then addes nbsp; to html (second one). It might explain 2 records after other character after space (inserting new character and removing nbsp;)

Comment: @PatrickEvans I can confirm that this behavior is due to nbsp; insertion in dom. I set div style white-space: pre; and I got only one record per each space. then, I don't have the nbps;